# Hide price of specific product in PrestaShop product display page

Tags: prestashop

I want to hide the price of a specific product in PrestaShop.

I have the basic idea in creating a module and I've created a module. I want to load the product name id and a check box in the back office after clicking on the configure button. Hope modifying the code like `Db::getInstance()->executeS(‘SELECT * FROM ‘._DB_PREFIX_.’product’);` can help me but I couldn't find a way to put it and get the values from database.

I also want to save the values which are checked in the configuration page and while viewing the product page if the product id has a check box value 1 then the price will not be shown. Can someone give me some tips on how to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes I've already created a dummy module and created the configuration page but stuck in displaying the products in back-office and assigning the value in the product page. My idea is to check the value if it has a hide price option on then it'll skip the price display option. Don't you thing this question is helpful ? Have you ever used prestashop ? without evaluating the value of a question you shouldn't down grade it.

Comment: _without evaluating the value of a question you shouldn't down grade it._ I don't doubt that your problem is valid, but without some sign of research there's not much to differentiate it from any other "can you do this for me" type question. I went ahead and removed my downvote; just for future reference, please mention any research you've done in the original question.

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion and improvements to my question. I really need to improve my English. Well I have created a module in my pc and working on it locally. Let me add the cod to github. Hope that will work.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get an admin panel for your module is to create an AdminController for your module and use the basic form helper use by prestashop. Here is how to do it :

- Create your class in "mymodule/controllers/admin/AdminmymoduleController.php" (create the file first, replace by your module name)
- Set the contructor up by defining important information. If you don't know what to do, just look at another core admin class (like "AdminContactsControllerCore")
- Override the renderForm method to set up the "fields_form" property with your own fields. You can again look at another admin class, but the the most important fields you need to fill is "$this->fields_form"
- Create a new tab in your module installation method. You should do something like :
  $this->installModuleTab('Adminmymodule', array(1 => 'Attribute description'), $idTabParent = 9)

EDIT :

There is the function installModuleTab

```
private function installModuleTab($tabClass, $tabName, $idTabParent) {
    @copy(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->name . '/logo.png',
        _PS_IMG_DIR_ . 't/' . $tabClass . '.png');
    $tab = new Tab();
    $tab->name = $tabName;
    $tab->class_name = $tabClass;
    $tab->module = $this->name;
    $tab->id_parent = $idTabParent;
    if (!$tab->save())
      return false;
    return true;
  }
```

I'm sorry but i can't do more without "making it for you", but i hope that can help you anyway.

Comment: Thank You it gave me a boost. I'm working on it. I'll let you know if any specific help needed.

Comment: I added the function installModuleTab, i forgot it, my bad